# Why foreach on PlaceHolder.Controls throws "Collection was modified"?

Tags: c#, asp.net, exception, foreach

```
protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
{
    HtmlGenericControl div1 = new HtmlGenericControl("div"); 
    div1.Attributes.Add("class", "modalbox");
    if (!ClientVisible)
        div1.Attributes.CssStyle.Add("display", "none");
    HtmlGenericControl div2 = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
    div2.Attributes.Add("class", "modalbox-m1");
    HtmlGenericControl div3 = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
    div3.Attributes.Add("class", "modalbox-m2");
    foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
        div3.Controls.Add(c); // exception here 
    div2.Controls.Add(div3);
    div1.Controls.Add(div2);
    div1.RenderControl(writer);
}
```

I can't understand WHO and WHERE changes `this.Controls`?

Comment: override the `CreateChildControls` method and place the above code and check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `c`, being a [`Control`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), *has a single [Parent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.parent%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)* and a two-way relationship is established when the control is added to a [`ControlCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). The same Control *will not* exist in multiple ControlCollections, unless something is broken.

So when `c` is added to `div3`, it first [removes itself](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.remove%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) from the previous parent container - in this case that is `c.Parent.Controls`, the same object as `this.Controls`, which is being iterated. The end-result is the modification exception, as adding the control to a different collection removes it from the iterated collection ..

The simplest way to avoid this exception is to *create a copy* of the collection, as with [`IEnumerable.ToList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342261%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). The new list, being independent from the ControlCollection, is not modified when the control is removed.

```
// Note the "ToList()", from LINQ/Enumerable
foreach (Control c in this.Controls.ToList()) {
    div3.Controls.Add(c); // exception here 
}
```

However, adding controls as such inside `Render` is *"fairly suspect"* and there are many cases in which it will *break* controls across postbacks.

---

If I just wanted to wrap the control collection *in code* and the markup does not affect the control tree, then I would use something like the following to generate the appropriate rendered output *without* creating new controls or otherwise modifying the control tree. [HtmlTextWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) provides all the basic methods to generate the relevant markup, even if it can be tedious.

```
protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
{
    writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Class, "modalbox");
    if (!ClientVisible) {
        writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Style, "display: none");
    }
    writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Div); // div1

    writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Class, "modalbox-m1");
    writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Div); // div2

    writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Class, "modalbox-m2");
    writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Div); // div3

    // Render children.
    // None of the control collections are altered in this process.
    // (This may render other content if sub-classing an
    //  existing control; in that case, loop and render the
    //  the children individually, if such is appropriate.)
    base.Render(writer);

    writer.RenderEndTag(); // div3   
    writer.RenderEndTag(); // div2
    writer.RenderEndTag(); // div1
}
```

Tip: RenderBeginTag/RenderEndTag work as a stack, and attributes set via AddAttribute always apply to the next RenderBeginTag.

---

In practice though, I highly recommend (and frequently use) [User Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y6wb1a0e%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) which allow ASCX Markup and creating the control tree declarative.

Comment: Good answer! All I want is to wrap content of my custom control based on PlaceHolder with 3 divs. Maybe I do it in wrong place?

Comment: @Denis Just add it to the Placeholder control (or some suitable derivative directly) - OnPreRender is the *latest* that a control collection can be reliably modified, but it should often happen sooner (in OnLoad or even a PostBack event).

Comment: @Denis I recommend using UserControls (so that much of the control can be written in Markup), but creating a custom ServerControl is also suitable. Then in the Render of the control: `/* write before HTML */ /* render child controls, but don't move them */ /* write end HTML */` (with a UserControl and ASCX, the HTML is of course "written" in the Markup which is why I prefer it).

Comment: I've tried different techniques, in particular UserControls. It has at least one serious drawback: I am unable to access nested controls directly from page methods without `FindCountrol` (for instance, `this.MyTextBox1.Text = "abc"`). So, I've switched to ServerControl based on `PlaceHolder` (which, obviously, provides me with required functionality). The only question now is where and how to wrap `this.Controls` with extra divs. Any ideas?

Comment: I am developing a generic control (modal dialog box). It may contain any number of nested controls, absolutely like `Panel` or (better) `PlaceHolder`.

Comment: @Denis I've added a snippet of how I would approach it if the rendering did not have any effect on the control tree.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47069/discussion-between-denis-and-user2864740)

Answer (score 1):

Your code is what is changing it by adding the control in this.controls to the div3 collection.

I don't know the exact mechanics, but I suspect that this action causes a re-parenting of `c`, which affects `this.controls`.

The solution is to change it to a for loop that works backwards through `this.controls`:

```
        for (int i = this.Controls.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            Control c = this.Controls[i];
            div3.Controls.Add(c);
        }
```

Comment: `div3` is `HtmlGenericControl` created few lines above. As I understand it is absolutely isolated from `this`. I populate its `Controls` list - why `this.Controls` changes? Can't understand.

Comment: @denis: the issue is that when you add an item from the this.Controls collection to the div3.Controls collection, there is likely an internal operation that implicitly removes the control from this.Controls and adds it to div3.Controls. In web, the Controls collections are all hierarchical, so this.Controls does not represent every control in the page, only those at the top level.

Answer (score 1):

My final solution:

```
protected override void CreateChildControls()
{
    HtmlGenericControl div1 = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
    div1.Attributes.Add("class", "modalbox");
    if (!ClientVisible)
        div1.Attributes.CssStyle.Add("display", "none");
    HtmlGenericControl div2 = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
    div2.Attributes.Add("class", "modalbox-m1");
    HtmlGenericControl div3 = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
    div3.Attributes.Add("class", "modalbox-m2");
    div1.Controls.Add(div2);
    div2.Controls.Add(div3);
    while (Controls.Count != 0)
        div3.Controls.Add(Controls[0]);
    Controls.Add(div1);
}
```